# creating custom events for plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to know how to create my own custom events for my plugin and how to fire the event. My addItem function works but I don't know how to make my own custom event to work does anyone know?

```
$('#TreeView').Web().DropDownList().onload(function () {
    alert('loaded function event');
}).click(function () {
    $(this).addItem('Hello World');
});

$.fn.Web = function () {
     var $this = this;
     return {
        TreeView: function () {
            return $this.each(function () {
                alert('TreeViewControl');
            })
        },
        DropDownList: function () {
           var methods = {
               addItem: function () {
                   alert('AddItem');
               }, removeItem: function () {
                  alert('removeItem');
               }
            }

            return $this.each(function () {
                //methods.addItem.apply(this, arguments);
                for (var method in methods) {
                    methods[method].apply(this, arguments);
                }
                return this;
            })
        }
    }
};
```